# Event-B total function proof obligation

Tags: event-b

I have question as follows: A set `A` is defined and total function `X` with invariant type

```
X ∈ A --> BOOL
```

and an event `A_setSate`:

```
A_setSate =
  WHEN X(A) = TRUE
  THEN X(A) := FALSE
```

the problem is that the proof obligation event preservation (INV) of `A_setState` cannot preserve the invariant `X∈ A--> BOOL`:

[image]

I know it is because of the invariant is not strong enough, but I could not create a stronger invariant.

full example : [Example snipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMbir.png)

Answer (score 0):

The example looks correct.

Please check if the Atelier B provers are installed, the [Rodin Handbook](https://www3.hhu.de/stups/handbook/rodin/current/html/tut_install_plugins.html) contains instructions for this.

(This answer had been updated after some clarifications in the comments.)

Comment: Yes I have an error here , but in RODIN I have wrote A_setState as your example with parameter ,but , proof obligation still not proved.

Comment: I haven't tried out the example myself because I do not have Rodin installed on my current machine. But it seems correct to me. Are you sure that you have the provers installed? If yes, can you show us the complete event and invariant?

Comment: I have edited my question and added snipping of full example .
what you mean by provers installed ,  auto prover is integrated with RODIN, is there a prover to be installed?

Comment: The Atelier B Prover plugin should be installed: https://www3.hhu.de/stups/handbook/rodin/current/html/tut_install_plugins.html

Comment: Thanks a lot , I do not know how to thank you, I install this prover and all proof obligations is proved , Thanks

Comment: That's easy. :) Just vote for the answer and mark it as the answer to your question. I have updated it accordingly.